# selecting 1 row having multiple rows?

Tags: sql, date, max, rows

I have a query that cannot be changed. for example:

```
SELECT studentid FROM school s LEFT OUTER JOIN mall m ON s.studentid=m.studentid
```

A student has two rows in the table Mall. The query above outputs duplicates because the student has two rows with the same id on the table mall.There is a date column on the table mall, and I just want to select the student with the most latest date. how do i do it?(just adding condition to the where clause)

Answer (score 1):

```
where m.date=(select max(date) from mall where studentid=m.studentid)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select s.studentid 
from school s 
INNER JOIN malls m1 ON m1.studentid = s.studentid
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT studentid, Max(DateField) MaxDate 
   FROM mall
   GROUP BY studentid
) m2 on m1.studentid = m2.studentid AND m1.DateField = m2.MaxDate
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT studentid 
FROM school s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN mall m 
ON s.studentid=m.studentid
ORDER BY date DESC
GROUP BY studentid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use order by and limit like bellow:

```
select studentid 
from school s 
left outer join mall m on s.studentid=m.studentid 
order by date desc 
limit 1
```

It's more simple way than use multiple select query on where clause.

Comment: This will select only one record total.

Comment: Actually, looking back at the question, maybe that was what was wanted.  So never mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `SQL Server`

```
WITH LatestRecord
AS
(
    SELECT  studentID, date,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition BY StudentID Order By DATE DESC) AS RN
    FROM    mall
)
SELECT  a.*, b.studentID, b.date
FROM    School a
        INNER JOIN LatestRecord b
            on a.StudentID = b.Student_ID
WHERE   RN = 1
```